# VS2012, How to solve WPF designer assembly resolving issues?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

I have a small empty solution with one project. This projects refers to some other assemblies. One of these is `DesignSystem`.

In code I can now access all public classes etc. in `DesignSystem`.

In XAML I include some of these namespaces like

```
xmlns:ds="clr-namespace:Mango.DesignSystem;assembly=DesignSystem"
```

But it then marks usage of that namespace with an error:

```
<TextBlock Margin="{x:Static ds:Margins.ThicknessMedium}"
```

Error:

```
Error   4   The name "Margins" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Mango.DesignSystem;assembly=DesignSystem".
```

Nevertheless the project compiles and runs fine.

Also when I import a namespace in XAML Intellisense tries to help and offers me: all .NET namespaces, all project namespaces and other third party assembly namespaces but not those of `DesignSystem`.

How can I learn why the designer says something like that / how can I debug this?

Comment: Have you tried a clean and a rebuild? Clean- rebuild- restart :) Helped me a few times. Designer is so and so sometimes in VS12. Make sure you have the latest updates.

Comment: @IrisClasson Yeah I know it is wacky sometimes ;)  Cleanup, Rebuild, Restart VS, Reboot computer, Update 3 installed, all tried :(